# Is this a valid parametrization?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

I was trying to solve the following problem, but I am not sure about my solution.Problem:

Let $P = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x = y\}$, and let $f \colon U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be given by

\begin{equation*}
 f(u,v) = (u + v, u + v, uv)
\end{equation*}
where $U = \{(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid u > v\}$. Clearly, $f(U) \subset P$. Is $f$ a parametrization of $P$?

Solution: No. This function $f$ does not cover $P$. For example, points of the form $(2x_0, 2x_0, x_0^2)$ where $x_0 > 0$ are never covered by $f$. Is my solution correct? Is it this simple?

Comment: Oh, it took me a while to see what you're doing. So $U$ does not allow $u=v$, and so the point you gave, which is $f(x_0,x_0)$, appears not to be in $f(U)$. But you do need to check that there is no point $(u,v)\in U$ with $f(u,v)$ equal to that point. Do the algebra.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This surface lies entirely in a plane $ x=y$  patch, it is simple. The generators have an envelope as a parabola. It is projection of the more familiar patch of parametrization.
$$ (x,y,z)=(u + v,\,0, \,u v)  $$

where we divide tangent points to vertex meeting point tangent segment proportionately and draw the connecting rays forming the parabolic envelope.

[image: ProjectionHyperbolicParaboloid]

$u,v$ can be interchaged, we get a coincident point for two sets of $ (u,v) $ but still has full cover.

It is worth looking at saddle points of a 3-space surface hyperbolic paraboloid in this projected connection of parametrization $ (u+v,\,u-v, \,uv )$ to appreciate special case covering.

Comment: If you use the whole $uv$-plane, you get a branched double-cover of the plane $P$. But restricting to the domain $U$ (which I think you ignored), you get a single cover of $P$ *except* for the points the OP suggested.